# JFET biasing problem

Tags: design, voltage-divider, bias, fet

I tried solving this problem, however I feel like there's something missing, I am asked to bias a N-channel JFET with using this provided data:

- Idss= 12 [mA]
- VDD= 12 [V]
- VP = -5 [V]
- VDS=VDD/2

using a voltage divider circuit, however I can't seem to get an equation for the resistance values.

Here's what I've done so far: [image: The circuit]

[image: What I've done so far]

Comment: The \$V_{DS}\$ spec tells you how much voltage can be across \$R_S\$ and \$R_D\$, but it seems like you need to know the desired output voltage (whether the output is \$V_D\$ or \$V_S\$).

Answer (score 1):

You "*feel like there's something missing*" in the task... and you are right, there are missing two pieces of information to determine the required bias (\$ V_{GS} \$).

From the given information you can write:

$$ I_D = \frac{V_{DD}}{2 \cdot (R_S + R_D)} = \frac{k \cdot V_{DD} - V_{GS}}{R_S} = I_{DSS} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{V_{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2 $$ where \$k\$ is the \$ R_1, R_2 \$ divider ratio \$ \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \$.

So you have to know either:

1. \$ R_S, k \$ and you can calculate the required \$ V_{GS} \$, (then \$ I_D \$ and \$ R_D  \$), or
2. \$ R_S, R_D \$ and you can calculate \$ I_D \$, then the required \$ V_{GS} \$ (and finally \$k\$), or
3. \$ R_D, k \$ and again calculate the rest

Then, to solve the \$ R_1, R_2 \$ divider out of the \$k\$ value, you have to know (choose) value of one of the resistors (or their sum), of course.